# Modify href value using Jquery for specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for this html ,

```
<a href='/profiles/UDP/1' class="putmehere">profile1</a> 
<a href='/profiles/UDP/2' class="putmehere">profile2</a> 
<a href='/profiles/UDP/3' class="dontputmehere">profile3</a> 
<a href='/profiles/UDP/4' class="putmehere">profile4</a> 
<a href='/profiles/UDP/5' class="putmehere">profile5</a> 
<a href='/profiles/UDP/6' class="dontputmehere">profile6</a>
```

I want to append value to `href` , something like  `href='/profiles/UDP/1/site=4'` for all anchor tags having class `putmehere`.

How to do this using Jquery ?

### UPDATE

Want to append `/site=4` to existing href attribute.

Comment: I was thinking you want to set value depending of the current href like e.g `site=1` for `href='/profiles/UDP/1'`. But then, you should have find answer easily if you'd have searched for it...

Comment: Why Negative vote again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) for this purpose

```
$(".putmehere").attr("href","/profiles/UDP/1/site=4");
```

If you want to append "site=4", then try like this

```
$(".putmehere").each(function(){
$(this).attr("href", ($(this).attr('href') + "/site=4"));
})
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.attr()` to set attribute.use:

```
$(".putmehere").attr('href','/profiles/UDP/1/site=4');
```

For appending in end of every `href` :

```
$(".putmehere").each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '/site=4');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for `.each()`. Use `.attr()` with function value.

```
$(".putmehere").attr("href", function(i,val){
   return val + "/site=4";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to append `/site=4` to all anchor with class

```
$(".putmehere").each(function(){
    $(this).prop("href", $(this).prop('href') + "/site=4");
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7b2LL/)

If you want to modify it. Then use

```
$(".putmehere").prop('href','/profiles/UDP/1/site=4');
```

Comment: Downvoter atleast provide comments for when you downvote

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$("a.putmehere").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?site=4");  
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pd5H/)